# codeigniter image upload and resize - swfupload

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter, swfupload, image-uploading

I am currently coding up a portion of site that allows the user to upload an image, and then choose an area of that image to crop. I am wanting it so that that image is uploaded without the user having to submit the form, so I using a tool called swfupload, I have managed to get the image uploading, however I cannot get swfupload to create a thumbnail or even read in my thumbnail method.

Below is my code,

PHP

```
public function upload()
    {
        $config['upload_path'] = "./media/uploads/users";
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size']    = '1000';
        $config['max_width']  = '1024';
        $config['max_height']  = '768';
        $config['encrypt_name']  = TRUE;

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);


        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('Filedata'))
        {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            //die(print_r($error));
        }
        else
        {
            $this->file = $this->upload->data();
            echo $this->file['file_name'];
        }
    }

    public function thumbnail()
    {
                //lets just try and get thumbnail() talking to swfupload
        echo 1;
    }
```

swfupload js

```
window.onload = function () {
            swfu = new SWFUpload({
                // Backend Settings
                upload_url: "http://lcl.moovjob.com/index.php/admin/users/upload",
                post_params: {"PHPSESSID": "<?php echo $this->session->userdata('session_id'); ?>" },

                // File Upload Settings
                file_size_limit : "5 MB",   // 5MB
                file_types : "*.jpg",
                file_types_description : "JPG Images",
                file_upload_limit : "0",

                // Event Handler Settings - these functions as defined in Handlers.js
                //  The handlers are not part of SWFUpload but are part of my website and control how
                //  my website reacts to the SWFUpload events.
                file_queue_error_handler : fileQueueError,
                file_dialog_complete_handler : fileDialogComplete,
                upload_progress_handler : uploadProgress,
                upload_error_handler : uploadError,
                upload_success_handler : uploadSuccess,
                upload_complete_handler : uploadComplete,

                // Button Settings
                button_image_url : "images/SmallSpyGlassWithTransperancy_17x18.png",
                button_placeholder_id : "spanButtonPlaceholder",
                button_width: 180,
                button_height: 18,
                button_text : '<span class="button">Select Images <span class="buttonSmall">(2 MB Max)</span></span>',
                button_text_style : '.button { font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12pt; } .buttonSmall { font-size: 10pt; }',
                button_text_top_padding: 0,
                button_text_left_padding: 18,
                button_window_mode: SWFUpload.WINDOW_MODE.TRANSPARENT,
                button_cursor: SWFUpload.CURSOR.HAND,

                // Flash Settings
                flash_url : "/media/flash/swfupload.swf",

                custom_settings : {
                    upload_target : "divFileProgressContainer"
                },

                // Debug Settings
                debug: true
            });
        };
```

My Handlers js, in particular the upload success method,

```
function uploadSuccess(file, serverData) {
    try {
        var progress = new FileProgress(file,  this.customSettings.upload_target);

        if (serverData.substring(0, 7) === "FILEID:") {
            addImage("http://local.test.com/index.php/admin/users/thumbnail");

            progress.setStatus("Thumbnail Created.");
            progress.toggleCancel(false);
        } else {
            addImage("images/error.gif");
            progress.setStatus("Error.");
            progress.toggleCancel(false);
            alert(serverData);

        }


    } catch (ex) {
        this.debug(ex);
    }
}
```

What am i doing for the time being all I want to is for the image to upload and then return 1 so I know swfupload is talking to my controller. All i get back is upload success or error.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery file uplaoder with Image area select plugin of jquery.
This is the URL for image area select plugin:
http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused why you don't add the thumbnail method to the end of your upload function? There is no need to do these operations seperately as far as I can think of.

You already have a check for successful uploads in your upload function, so before it returns any data, pass the filename/dir to your thumbnail function, create the thumbnail and then return success or failure to your js that way.